# Dec to bin converter function printing result out backwards

Tags: c, recursion, converters

As part of an exercise, I have to rewrite a recursive function so that the new function is not recursive. Both functions need to convert positive decimal integer inputs into their binary equivalent.

This is the code using recursion:

```
void convert(int n) { //recursive
  if (n > 0) {
    convert(n/2);
    printf("%d", n%2);
  }

  return;
}
```

Here's my code:

```
void convert(int n) { //non-recursive
  while (n > 0) {
    printf("%d", n%2);
    n/=2;
  }

  return;
}
```

The problem with my code is that, understandably, my binary conversion gets printed out backwards. For example, if I enter the number 8, my function returns 0001, if I enter 2, 01 is returned, etc.

Any suggestions for a quick fix using only the `stdio.h` library?

Comment: The first code segment is not using recursion ... Should `foo3` be `convert`?

Comment: Nice catch. I fixed that.

Comment: Output to an array then print the array.

Comment: Understand that for integer values (unsigned) `n/2` is the same as `n >> 1` but the division is much more computationally expensive, as is the modulo computation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a non-recursive version that produces the same result as your recursive version and doesn't require an array:

```
void convert(int n) {
    int     s;

    for (s = 1; n/s/2 > 0; s *= 2)
        ;

    for (; s >= 1; s /= 2) {
        printf("%d", (n/s) % 2);
    }
}
```

This version handles zero and large numbers (but not negative numbers).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one loop:

```
if(num == 0) {
    printf("0\n");  // Check for num being 0.
    return;
}

num = num < 0 ? num*-1 : num; // Make sure the number has no sign bit. 
char first1Found = 0; // Create a check for the first 1 printed.
for (int i = sizeof(num)*8 - 1; i >= 0 ; --i) {
    if (num & (1 << i)) { // If its a 1, print it and set the first1Found bool.
        printf("1");
        first1Found = 1;
    } else if(first1Found) { // If its a 0 only print it if its not a leading 0.
        printf("0");
    }
}
printf("\n");
```

[Here is a live example.](http://ideone.com/4AcEJR)

Note: I have used 8 by making an assumption that `sizeof` returns bytes in a type. This may not be true of all systems and compilers (although should be). A more portable way might be to use `CHAR_BIT` from `<limits.h>` as suggested by @chux.

Comment: This fails to remove leading zeroes, so doesn't really work.

Comment: You have to shift an *unsigned* `1u` into the sign bit.

Comment: Do not use `printf` to print a single character `putchar (num & (1 << i) ? '1' : '0');` and then `putchar ('\n');`

Comment: `8` is assumed ( a good assumption, but an assumption).  Could use `CHAR_BIT` instead of `8`, but that is in `<limits.h>` which goes against " using only the stdio.h".

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks, i didnt think of that, fixed.

Comment: @WeatherVane I removed the sign bit, the above implementation doesn't care about negatives either.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Why? Its not like its being printed at 10MHz.

Comment: @chux, True, I will mention that.

Comment: @Ben - not knowing how many times you are calling it, it's up to you. If you are only calling it a couple to a couple thousand times -- it doesn't matter, if you are calling it a billion times it does.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant that's explicit about using bit-masking and shifting the location of the mask from the upper end downwards.  It behaves like your recursive version, in that it doesn't do negatives or zero.

```
void convert(int n) {
  for(int mask = 1 << (8 * sizeof(n) - 2); mask > 0; mask >>= 1) {
    if (mask <= n) {
      putchar((n & mask) ? '1' : '0');
    }
  }
  putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: Assumes 8 - see [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660471/dec-to-bin-converter-function-printing-result-out-backwards/35662391#comment59005473_35660785)

Comment: @chux - thx.  Given the "only stdio" request, I'll leave it as-is.

Answer (score 0):

A reliable way to print an unpadded binary representation of an unsigned valued (any size capable of fitting within a `long unsigned`) is:

```
/** unpadded binary representation of 'v'. */
void binprn (const unsigned long v)
{
    if (!v)  { putchar ('0'); return; };

    size_t sz = sizeof v * CHAR_BIT;
    unsigned long rem = 0;

    while (sz--)
        if ((rem = v >> sz))
            putchar ((rem & 1) ? '1' : '0');
}
```

(`CHAR_BIT` (usually `8`) is provided in `limits.h`). You do not "*need*" to use `limits.h` -- that's just where it `CHAR_BIT` is normally found. All you need is a constant, you can call it anything you like. I generally just use:

```
/* CHAR_BIT */
#ifndef CHAR_BIT
#define CHAR_BIT  8
#endif
```

Comment: Using `CHAR_BIT` from `<limits.h>` goes against "using only the stdio.h library".

Comment: Far too literal of a reading. I simply noted where it was provided, but did not say you needed to include `limits.h`. All you need is the constant. (any named constant setting the number of bits-per-byte will do).

Answer (score 0):

C99 variation on [@Tom Karzes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35660739/2410359) fine answer that handles all + and - values including `INT_MIN`.

```
void convertm(int n) {
  if (n < 0) {
    putchar('-');
  } else {
    n = -n;
  }

  // Build up a negative power-of-2 that meets/exceeds `n`
  int npow2;
  for (npow2 = -1; n/2 <= npow2 ; npow2 *= 2)
    ;

  // For each negative power-of-2 ...
  while (npow2) {
    putchar(n / npow2 + '0');
    n %= npow2;
    npow2 /= 2;
  }
  puts("");
}
```